# ODATA - query field with type Int64

Tags: web-services, odata

I'm trying to query field (from my ODATA service), who has type of Int64. Query looks like:

```
http://localhost/Data/MyTable?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=100&%24filter=BIGID+eq+666423361622
```

But it throws exception -

```
"An error occurred while processing this request".
```

After checking exception details in debug mode, I found the real exception -

```
{System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32...}
```

Is there a way, that I could make ODATA not use parse to Int32? Maybe something like:

```
filter=(Int64)BIGID+eq+666423361622
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Int64 literals should be in the format of [-] [0-9]+L, so in your case 666423361622L (note the L letter at the end). This is as per http://www.odata.org/documentation/overview#AbstractTypeSystem.